# Combining rows based on aliases in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2009,2008,2010,2009),
  uid = c(7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12, 13,14,14,14),
  value1=c(2,3,6,4,3,2,1,4,5,6),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df
   year uid value1
1  2011   7      2
2  2011   8      3
3  2010   9      6
4  2010  11      4
5  2009  12      3
6  2010  12      2
7  2009  13      1
8  2008  14      4
9  2010  14      5
10 2009  14      6
```

I have another dataframe that has aliases for the unique identifiers, like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
uidAliases = c("7,11", "8,13", "9,12,14")
)
```

First, I want to replace uid based on the df2$uidAliases and then I want to combine the value1 based on uid, year. Basically, what I need is that if there are additional aliases for an uid, the later ones should get replaced. (I know how to do the 2nd part but I am struggling with matching and replacing the UIDs. Much appreciated!)

The final output should look like this:

```
outputdf <- data.frame(
  year = c(2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2009,2009,2008),
  uid = c(7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 8,9),
  value1=c(2,3,13,4,9,1,4),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) 

year uid value1
1 2011   7      2
2 2011   8      3
3 2010   9     13
4 2010   7      4
5 2009   9      9
6 2009   8      1
7 2008   9      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% separate(
  uidAliases,
  into = c("main_uid", paste0("V", 1:max(
    str_count(.$uidAliases, ",")
  ))),
  sep = ",",
  fill = "right"
) %>%
  pivot_longer(-main_uid, values_to = "uid") %>%
  filter(!is.na(uid)) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "uid") %>%
  mutate(main_uid = coalesce(main_uid, uid)) %>%
  group_by(main_uid, year) %>%
  summarize(value1 = sum(value1))
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   main_uid [3]
#   main_uid  year value1
#      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1        7  2010      4
# 2        7  2011      2
# 3        8  2009      1
# 4        8  2011      3
# 5        9  2008      4
# 6        9  2009      9
# 7        9  2010     13
```

Most of the work is in getting the comma-separated aliases into the usable format of a lookup table. After that, it's a standard join and grouped sum.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach. You can use `separate_rows()` to split the second dataframe. Then, creating a common key between both dataframes will allow joining them to finally create the expected summary:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
      separate_rows(uidAliases,sep=',') %>%
      group_by(id) %>% mutate(key=min(as.numeric(uidAliases))) %>%
      ungroup() %>% dplyr::select(-id) %>%
      mutate(uidAliases=as.numeric(uidAliases)) %>%
      rename(uid=uidAliases)
  ) %>%
  group_by(year,key) %>%
  summarise(value1=sum(value1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   year [4]
   year   key value1
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2008     9      4
2  2009     8      1
3  2009     9      9
4  2010     7      4
5  2010     9     13
6  2011     7      2
7  2011     8      3
```